# gstreamer WebRTC unidirectional broadcasting?

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer

I'm a begginer to WebRTC & gstreamer and I have a question.

I've been struggling with gstreamer WebRTC example, webrtc-unidirectional-h264.c, to broadcast IP camera.
I changed the pipeline as like below, at first it was just v4l2src.

```
 receiver_entry->pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch ("webrtcbin name=webrtcbin stun-server=stun://"
      STUN_SERVER " "
      "rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.5:554/stream1 tune=zerolatency latency=0 ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! "
      "x264enc bitrate=12288 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 name=payloader ! "
      "application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96"
      " ! webrtcbin. ", &error);
```

To show it in chrome with fullscreen I editted some flags in html description like below.

```
  <body> \n \
    <div> \n \
      <video id=\"stream\" autoplay muted></video> \n \
    </div> \n \
  </body> \n \
```

As far I know chrome doesn't play strema automatically, if I don't give muted option.

With the code I could make a webview stream page.
But if multiple user enter the page the latency of stream goes higher and higher.
For one user the latency of stream is about 300ms, but if four users enter the page the latency goes about 3secs.

I've been searching for the reason, but it's hard to find.

I estimated some reasons like below.

###### 1. Everytime another user enters the page, it opens another pipeline so it might be a burden to camera

I made a multicast server to check whether it is true, but I think it's not the fact. Though I opened the multicast server and use that source, latency goes higher as number of user increases.

###### 2. Everytime another user enters the page, it opens another pipeline so it might be burden to soup server

I'm begginer to WebRTC, so I've been searching this but I didn't find related issue

###### 3. Everytime another user enters the page, the gst WebRTC pipeline needs to make a tee to work properly

Now I'm trying to make this work, if I got some progress I'll update it to this issue.

I tried to change some option of gst pipeline like bitrate of encoder, type of decoder&encoder.
And I tried to change source IP camera(RTSP), multicast server(via RTP), media server(RTSP).
But it doesn't work

What I expect is that multiple user can see the same stream of camera without latency.

Can you give me advices?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline is good but each time a new user connects :

- You connects to the camera ( bandwidth consumption )
- You encode the stream you receive ( CPU intensive Consumption )
- Then you send video to your connected user.

As you previouly said a tee could be a good idea, you can also if you want reuse encoding stream from your camera ( only if it is a constrained baseline profile, higher profiles are not supported by all navigators ).

Your pipeline main pipeline should be like that :

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.5:554/stream1 tune=zerolatency latency=0 ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! x264enc bitrate=12288 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=50 ! h264parse ! tee name=m
```

Then on each connection :

```
m. ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96' ! webrtcbin
```

( I think you can also put  rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96' before the tee)

I you want to use camera encoder :

```
    rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.5:554/stream1 tune=zerolatency latency=0 ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tee name=m
```

On each connection the tee should be the same.

You can do that only if the camera profile is constrained-bandwidth.

If you share the encoder you need ensure that key-frame-interval is regular ( key-int-max for x264enc )

Other thing you seem to have Nvidia hardware may be nvenc element could be better for reduce you cpu usage.

You can contact me if you need a concrete implementation.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I'm really appreciate for your kind advice. Can I ask you another question?   Can I add another gstreamer factory or elements to gst_parse_launch(main pipeline) while the main pipeline's state is GST_STATE_PLAYING? Thank you! I hope you have a happy day!

Comment: What I mean is that I think the main pipeline with tee=m should be in GST_STATE_PLAYING state and another pipeline starts with m. ! can get data from main pipeline? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure you can : Here an example : https://tewarid.github.io/2011/06/06/gstreamer-pipeline-with-tee.html
Have a nice day :) !